# TypeError: cards.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn react with hooks and at this point I am totally blind to what the issue is. The list renders correctly, but when I press the button I get a 'TypeError: cards.map is not a function' in my renderCardList().
Any help is mightily appreciated.

It works when i use the state in a class

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RentalCard from './RentalCard';

const RentalCardList = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([
        { name: 'Anne`s', price: 234 },
        { name: 'John`s', price: 83 },
        { name: 'Mary`s', price: 733 }
    ]);

    const renderCardList = () => {
        return cards.map(c => (
            <RentalCard key={Math.random()} name={c.name} price={c.price} />
        ));
    };

    const add = obj => {
        setCards(cards.push(obj));
        console.log(cards);
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <section id="rentalListing">
                <h1 className="page-title">Our hot listings</h1>
                <div className="row">{renderCardList()}</div>
            </section>
            <br />
            <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => add({ name: 'jon', price: 27 })}
            >
                View others
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RentalCardList;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with the way you're calling the `setCards` function to update `cards` state:

```js
const RentalCardList = () => {
  // ...

  const add = obj = {
    setCards(cards.push(obj))
  }
}
```

This is wrong, as per the MDN documentation:

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So when you're calling `cards.push(obj)` and setting the `cards` state with the return value from the `cards.push()` call, you're essentially just setting it to some integer, and your `cards` state is no longer an array.

Try this, instead:

```js
const RentalCardList = () => {
  const add = obj = {
    setCards([
      ...cards,
      obj
    ])
  }
}
```

This way, you're creating a new array, copying items from the "old" array, and adding a new value(s) to the new array.

This method is called `spread syntax` and if you'd like to learn more, MDN has a good explanation:

- [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals)

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
const add = obj => {
        setCards([...cards, obj]);
        console.log(cards);
    };
```